# How to auto update SUM query from database everytime there an item is added or an item is updated?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api

I'm building a pos system, I have a sum query from my database, how would I automatically update the sum value on the page every time there's an item added or an item is updated.

```
<?php 

require_once 'config.php';

$sql = 'SELECT tran_id , SUM(tran_amount) FROM tbl_transaction';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $total=$row['SUM(tran_amount)'];
    }

}
 echo "$total";
?>
```

How to make this total auto update when changes have been made in the database? I have been trying this in different ways but nothing works.

Here is my javacript code and not working. Is anyone can help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 update_total();

$(document).ready(function(){

 function update_total()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch_sumUpdate.php",
   success:function(data)
   {

     $('#total').text($total);
   }
  });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean updating the page every time a change is made in the database?

Comment: Try Ajax? Every time a user do an action that impact the database and this SUM : you call your php that get the sum value and update the front. Now if you want an update EVERY TIME a user do it, best is just to recalculate your sum value each XXX s and update it (so do an Ajax call with a set interval)

Comment: what shall the `SUM()` do with only one row??

Comment: sidenote: don't use mysql_* functions in new code. It's old, deprecated, removed. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: yes, spencdev but without reloading a page.

Comment: Try showing us your javascript. For a simple approach I'd do a AJAX request every x time to update that SUM value

Comment: now mysqli, Jeff

Comment: My  Javascript code is not working, now seen above, Pablo Moltedo

Comment: `$('#total').text($total);` should be `$('#total').text(data);`. $total is a php var, nothing to do with javascript. `data` is the return you get from ajax (=what you echo in php script)

Comment: `update_data()` will never be called (if this is the only call attempt you do), because you call it before it will be defined (which is only after all the html got rendered)

Comment: i already change Jeff, how would I call the value after the changes has been made?

Comment: the echo property is just a confirmation if my changes from mysql to mysqli is working.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I just add this code setTimeout("location.reload(true);",100) on JavaScript submit function. Tnx